# Problems with Jaxb generation

Tags: maven, xsd, jaxb

I have a problem with my JAXB-Generation. I have two XSDs (both in the same hierarchiy) which have a quite similiar schema-definition:

A.xsd

```
<xs:schema>
  <xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="CacheInfo">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="CacheType">
                  <xs:sequence ... />
                </xs:extension>
              </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element> <!--CacheInfo -->
       </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element> <!-- A -->
  <xs:complexType name="CacheType" ... />
  <xs:complexType name="TimeType" ... />
</xs:schema>
```

B.xsd

```
<xs:schema>
  <xs:element name="B">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element name="CacheInfo" type="CacheType">
         </xs:element> <!--CacheInfo -->
        <xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element> <!-- B -->
  <xs:complexType name="CacheType" ... />
  <xs:complexType name="TimeType" ... />
</xs:schema>
```

The structure of CacheType in this two XSDs is different. Its only the name the same.

My problem now is, that, when I try to generate the code I got this error: 
[ERROR] file:A.xsd [95,38]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:A.xsd; lineNumber: 95; columnNumber: 38; 'CacheType' is already defined (same issue for TimeType)

When I remove one of the files, the generation is ok. I am not able to edit the XSDs, so I need a binding-file to rename the types for the two special cases:

```
<bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/A.xsd" node="//xs:complexType[@name='CacheType']">
        <class name="ACacheType" />
</bindings>
<bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/B.xsd" node="//xs:complexType[@name='CacheType']">
        <class name="BCacheType" />
</bindings>
```

But this doesnt work. 
It also doesnt work, when I try to bind the types to a property (I am ending up in the same error):

```
<bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/A.xsd">
    <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='CacheType']">
        <property name="ACacheType" />
    </bindings>
    <bindings node=".//xs:complexType[@name='TimeType']">
        <property name="ATimeType" />
    </bindings>
</bindings>
<bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/B.xsd">
    <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='CacheType']">
        <property name="BCacheType" />
    </bindings>
    <bindings node=".//xs:complexType[@name='TimeType']">
        <class name="BTimeType" />
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Is there anything I dont see? Why I cant generate these two XSDs with these bindings?
To complete this, here is my pom.xml snippet:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-htng-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Possibly checking the obvious: are the binding files located in directory `/src/main/xjb`? The plugin looks in that directory for binding files. If they are in a different location, the plugin needs explicit configuration. See example 6 in the [plugin documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/example_xjc_basic.html).

Answer (score 0):

you need to define them at their own package
This will generate the same classes but in different packages, so it wont be a problem.

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/A.xsd">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="packagea" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/B.xsd">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="packageb" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

i havent used this plugin. i use the following:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                        <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</bindingDirectory>
                        <bindingIncludes>
                            <include>*.xjb</include>
                        </bindingIncludes>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</generateDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

you can try with this too to see if you get any errors.

Comment: that doesnt help at all :( 
here is my binding.xjb:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 version="1.0">
 <bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/A.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
  <schemaBindings>
         <package name="packagea" />
     </schemaBindings>
 </bindings>
 <bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/B.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
  <schemaBindings>
         <package name="packageb" />
     </schemaBindings>
 </bindings>
</bindings>`

Comment: i've used it a thousand times with more complex xsds and many classes in common and never had a problem.

Comment: any chance of sharing your project?

Comment: unfortunately not @sharing the project. the maven-jaxb2-plugin doesnt worked. i had to change my whole directories to try this and then my xsds lost their include-defs.

Comment: cant help you more. this is sth that i have used many times without any problem. i had the same problem but with defining different packages, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd ensure that the binding files are in the location expected by the `jaxb2-maven-plugin`. Specifying a package with a schemaBinding as mentioned by @Apostolos should have worked even without changing the plugin as I read the docs.

If the binding files are being applied, then one thing I notice is the bindings mentioned in the original question use a mix of `property` and `class`:

```
<bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/A.xsd">
  <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='CacheType']">
    <property name="ACacheType" />                         <!-- property -->
  </bindings>
  <bindings node=".//xs:complexType[@name='TimeType']">
    <property name="ATimeType" />                          <!-- property -->
  </bindings>
</bindings>
<bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/B.xsd">
  <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='CacheType']">
    <property name="BCacheType" />                         <!-- property -->
  </bindings>
  <bindings node=".//xs:complexType[@name='TimeType']">
    <class name="BTimeType" />                             <!-- class -->
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

[This document from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) has a section near the bottom on resolving conflicts. One example shows an element with name 'Class' which is a Java reserved word. They fix the conflict by specifying both property *and* class:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Class']">
  <jxb:class name="Clazz"/>
  <jxb:property name="Clazz"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

So I wonder, does it work if the binding is modified to specify both?

```
<bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/A.xsd">
  <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='CacheType']">
    <class name="ACacheType" />
    <property name="ACacheType" />
  </bindings>
  ... repeat for TimeType ....
</bindings>
```